Only the laser beams that navigate with the hands are displayed, but no AirTap or AirPinch interaction
I have the following problem: I want to act with Super Hands in an A-Frame environment Laser Pointer with the property AirTap and AirPinch. I have the following code, but it does not work. Only the laser beams that navigate with the hands are displayed, but no AirTap or AirPinch interaction.
Any idea?
<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <a-mixin id="pointer" raycaster="showLine: true; objects: .interactable"
             super-hands="colliderEvent: raycaster-intersection;
                          colliderEventProperty: els;
                          colliderEndEvent: raycaster-intersection-cleared;
                          colliderEndEventProperty: clearedEls;
                          grabStartButtons: airpinch; 
                          grabEndButtons: airpinch; 
                          stretchStartButtons: airtap; 
                          stretchEndButtons: airtap">
    </a-mixin>
    <a-mixin id="interactable" hoverable grabbable stretchable draggable droppable shadow></a-mixin>
  </a-assets>

  <!-- Kamera und Controller Setup -->
  <a-entity>
    <a-camera></a-camera>

    <!-- Linke Hand mit Hand Controls -->
    <a-entity id="left-hand" hand-controls="hand: left" line="color: red; opacity: 0.75" mixin="pointer"></a-entity>

    <!-- Rechte Hand mit Hand Controls -->
    <a-entity id="right-hand" hand-controls="hand: right" line="color: blue; opacity: 0.75" mixin="pointer"></a-entity>
  </a-entity>

  <!-- Text-Element für Feedback -->
  <a-text id="feedback" position="-1 2 -3" align="center" color="#FFF" value=""></a-text>

  <!-- Interaktive Objekte -->
  <a-box id="blueBox" class="interactable" mixin="interactable" color="blue" position="1 1 0" action-feedback></a-box>
  <a-box id="redBox" class="interactable" mixin="interactable" color="red" position="-1 1 0" action-feedback></a-box>
  <a-sphere id="greenSphere" class="interactable" mixin="interactable" color="green" position="3 1 0" action-feedback></a-sphere>
</a-scene>

This is my approach. I try hand controls and other, but no access
